# RTF to NSAttributedString with Tables (iOS)

Tags: ios, rtf, nsattributedstring

I'm using an RTF file as a template in an iOS App.  A part of this is a couple tables; however, when doing the conversion from RTF to NSAttributedString, the tables are lost.  If I sent them up as plain tabs, the formatting works.  However, since most of the text in each of the cells in the table are multi-line, tabs don't work.

Is there a way to either convert the tables from RTF in NSAttributedString or create tables directly within an NSAttributedString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, having found no real support for tables on NSAttributedString for iOS from either HTML or RTF, my solution was to build the pages in HTML, load them into a UIWebView, instead of loading the NSAttributedString into a UITextView.  This way I got the table formatting that I wanted and better yet, I had a view that I could use for creating PDFs of the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getText()
{
    do {
        let attibutedString = try NSAttributedString(url: rtfdFileUrl!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtfd], documentAttributes: nil)
        textView.attributedText = attibutedString
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

I tried this, but it is for rtfd, you can try rtf. It worked fine and the table was correct, but it would break if I tried to edit the text inside the table. If you only need to show the table it is fine.